# What ActiveRecord Transaction doesn't rollback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want an ActiveRecord transaction to fail on purpose. The issue is that the rollback isn't happening when I raise an ActiveRecord::Rollback exception (or any other exception). In the code bellow, the `perfom` method imports a file. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume it just updates a record:

```
puts "+++ Before Transaction +++"

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  puts "+++ In Transaction +++"
  perform

  puts "+++ Before Rollback +++"
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end

puts "+++ After Transaction +++"
```

When the code runs here's the output of the server:

```
+++ Before Transaction +++
+++ In Transaction +++
TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN
↳ app/models/import.rb:103:in `file_content'
Disk Storage (0.1ms) Downloaded file from key: abcdefg
Car Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."make" = '207' LIMIT 1
↳ app/models/application_record.rb:82:in `try_update_or_create_report'
Car Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "rolling_shutters_automatism_prices" WHERE 
"cars"."make" = '207' AND "cars"."id" != 5 LIMIT 1
↳ app/models/application_record.rb:106:in `try_update_report'
Car Update (0.2ms)  UPDATE "cars" SET "price" = 20.0, "updated_at" = '2023-12-26 15:17:47.978023' WHERE "cars"."id" = 5
↳ app/models/application_record.rb:106:in `try_update_report'
+++ Before Rollback +++
+++ After Transaction +++
```

The behaviour I would expect is to have `ROLLBACK` logged in between the 2 last line, but nothing is logged. Why is that?

I use rails 7.0.4 with postgres 15 and ruby 3.2.2

EDIT: I left out an important piece of information. The transaction happens within an ActiveRecord callback.

Comment: Just tried it and got the expected result. Is there any more magic happening in your applicaton_record-file?

Comment: Definitely something weird here, your logs don't show the `ROLLBACK` but they also don't show a `COMMIT`. Show the rest of your code, something very odd going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the transaction happened within an ActiveRecord callback. Since the callback is [itself wrapped in a transaction](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb#L250C2-L252C86), the transaction I was trying to perform was a [nested transaction](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-Nested+transactions). Therefore, raising an ActiveRecord::Rollback exception caused the outer transaction to rollback.

According to the documentation:

> In order to get a ROLLBACK for the nested transaction you may ask for a real sub-transaction by passing requires_new: true. If anything goes wrong, the database rolls back to the beginning of the sub-transaction without rolling back the parent transaction.

So the fixed example would look like this:

```
puts "+++ Before Transaction +++"

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(requires_new: true) do
  puts "+++ In Transaction +++"
  perform

  puts "+++ Before Rollback +++"
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
end

puts "+++ After Transaction +++"
```